# Is there a statement of Fubini's theorem for real integrals making no reference to multi-variable integrals?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

If $I$ and $J$ are two intervals of $\mathbb R$, then under what conditions can we say that

$$\int_I \int_J f(x, y) dx\ dy=\int_J \int_I f(x, y) dy\ dx$$

Obviously we have to assume that $f$ is such that all the integrals under consideration exist. But I'd like conditions that do not involve a double integral over $I\times J$. Is that possible?

Comment: If they're compact intervals and $f$ is continuous, you can interchange the order of integration, and you (can) prove that without using an integral over $I\times J$. You can generalise that to discontinuous $f$ if the discontinuities are nice enough, and to non-compact intervals for $f$ satisfying appropriate growth/decay conditions. You can invoke Tonelli's theorem, that the iterated integrals are equal if $f$ is measurable and $\int_I\int_J \lvert f(x,y)\rvert\,dx\,dy < \infty$ (but the proof may need to consider an integral over $I\times J$, I don't remember).

Comment: I am not sure I get it. It is probably about distinguishing between iterated integrals with 1d measures and the integral with a 2d measure?

Answer (score 0):

Daniel is correct, if the two measures are Lebesgue measures, it is enough to have the measurability of $f$ and $\int_I \int_J |f(x,y)| dx dy < \infty$. The idea is that when given these two conditions together with the fact that Lebesgue measure is $\sigma$-finite, by Tonelli's theorem we have 
$$\int_{I\times J} |f(x,y)| d(x\times y) = \int_I \int_J |f(x,y)| dx dy < \infty,$$
which is essentially the assumption for Fubini's Theorem.